# Como puedo insertar un dato de un array dentro de otro array de forma condicional?

Tags: php, array

Cordial saludo.
De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Tengo dos arrays bidimensionales de igual cantidad de filas, las cuales pueden aumentar su tamaño a N filas, Ejemplo:

```
Array1 ( 
[0] => Array ( [documento] => 1349587154 [nombres] => John Doe  [email] => prueba1@hotmail.com ) 
[1] => Array ( [documento] => 1093834332 [nombres] => Cosme Fulanito [email] => prueba2@hotmail.com) 
)



Array2 ( 
[0] => Array ( [documento] => 1349587154 [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1349587154/foto.png ) 
[1] => Array ( [documento] => 1093834332 [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1093834332/foto.png ) 
)
```

Quiero insertar la columna [url_foto] del array2 en el array1 donde el documento coincida, es decir, que el documento de la fila X del array2 coincida con el documento de la fila x del array1. Ya probé con arra_merge y con distintas funciones de manejo de array pero no he logrado hacerlo, **cabe destacar que no siempre van a estar en la misma posición de fila**

ejemplo de como debería quedar:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [documento] => 1349587154 [nombres] => John Doe  [email] => prueba1@hotmail.com [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1349587154/1728/foto.png ) 
[1] => Array ( [documento] => 1093834332 [nombres] => Cosme Fulanito [email] => prueba2@hotmail.com [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1093834332/1722/foto.png) 
)
```

Comment: Porque no le pasas el numero del documento como clave, algo como: ```$array1['1349587154'] = ['documento' => '1349587154','nombres' => 'John Doe','email' => 'prueba1@hotmail.com'];```, y así después fácilmente compruebas si las claves coincidan para añadir más valores.

Comment: Recorre el array1 y para cada elmento comprueba si está en el array 2 y si está recoje el valor e insertalo. Puedes usar el clásico bucle o un array_walk con una callback que se encargue de buscar el documento en el otro array y modificar el array1.
Para buscar un documento en un array define una función y para el calback lógicamente necesitas otra.

Comment: Bueno, otra opción es reconvertir los arrays en arrays donde el documento sea una key, mezclar estos arrays es un simple bucle. Luego se pueden recomvertir al formato original.

Comment: Mira a ver si te puede servir este ejemplo: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/e695b usando el nr documento como clave.

Comment: Tenia un error de concepto respecto a las claves, de antemano agradezco mucho la colaboración. Voy a ver el ejemplo que me acabas de pasar.

Comment: Creerías que no hay problemas con el ejemplo teniendo en cuenta que los valores del array son dinámicos?

Comment: ¿Por qué? No veo problema alguno para crear el array con datos dinámicos. Piensa que estas comparando el número del documento que va a ser único. Cuando obtienes los datos desde la base de datos tendrás que crear los *array1* y *array2* como el ejemplo. Y en mi ejemplo esta línea la podrías quitar ```'documento' => '1349587154'```, ya que la clave es el numero documento.

Comment: Te he dejado una actualización para que veas como puedes obtenerlo dinámico: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/5c01c a ver si así te orientas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136056/discussion-between-dbe-and-acris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi ejemplo usamos el número de documento como clave.

`$array1[($numero_documento)]`
`$array2[($numero_documento)]`

Estos los tendrás que crear dinámicamente con los datos obtenidos desde la Base de Datos, algo como:

```
foreach ($basedatos as $valor) :
    // Creamos array1 dinamico
    $array1[($valor['documento'])] = [
        'nombres' => $valor['nombres'],
        'email' => $valor['email']
    ];
endforeach;
```

Lo mismo tendrás que hacer con **array2**.
Veamos cómo queda el código completo.

**Posible ejemplo**

```
<?php
// Reseteo
$basedatos = $array1 = $array2 = [];

// supongamos que obtienes desde la BD
$basedatos[] = [
    'documento' => '1349587154',
    'nombres' => 'John Doe',
    'email' => 'prueba1@hotmail.com'
];

$basedatos[] = [
    'documento' => '1093834332',
    'nombres' => 'Cosme Fulanito',
    'email' => 'prueba2@hotmail.com'
];

// Recorres los datos que obteniste desde la BD para crear array 1, lo mismo se hace con array 2
foreach ($basedatos as $valor) :
    // Creamos array1 dinamico
    $array1[($valor['documento'])] = [
        'nombres' => $valor['nombres'],
        'email' => $valor['email']
    ];
endforeach;


// sigo creando array 2 manual, sera mismo proceso que arriba
$array2['1349587154'] = [
    'documento' => '1349587154',
    'url_foto' => 'https://enlace.com/Records/1349587154/foto.png'
];
$array2['1093834332'] = [
    'documento' => '1093834332',
    'url_foto' => 'https://enlace.com/Records/1093834332/foto.png',
];

// Actualizamos array 1 si el nr documento es igual en array 2
foreach ($array1 as $clave => $valor) {
    // Si existe la clave añadimos la url de la foto
    if (array_key_exists($clave, $array2)) $array1[($clave)]['url_foto'] = $array2[$clave]['url_foto'];
}


// Imprimimos array actualizado
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
echo '</pre>';
```

Ejemplo [Sandbox](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/5c01c)

Answer (score 2):

Esto lo puedes resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
foreach($array1 as $clave => $valor) {
    $clave_array2 = array_search($valor['documento'], array_column($array2, 'documento'));
    $array1[$clave]['url_foto'] = $array2[$clave_array2]['url_foto'];
}
print_r($array1);
```

que te devolverá:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [documento] => 1349587154
            [nombres] => John Doe
            [email] => prueba1@hotmail.com
            [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1349587154/foto.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [documento] => 1093834332
            [nombres] => Cosme Fulanito
            [email] => prueba2@hotmail.com
            [url_foto] => https://enlace.com/Records/1093834332/foto.png
        )

)
```

### Explicación detallada

- **$array1** se corresponde con tu *Array1*, y **$array2** con *Array2* de tu pregunta
- Para evitar ir creando variables nuevas, vamos a modificar **$array1** para agregarle la clave y valor que le viene de **$array2**
- Para ello vamos a recorrer *$array1* con un bucle [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) separando los datos de *$clave* y *$valor* de cada elemento del *$array1*:

```
foreach($array1 as $clave => $valor) {
```

- Luego vamos a buscar, en cada ciclo, y mediante [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search), el número de índice (o clave) en *$array2* donde la columna **'documento'** coincide con el *$valor['documento']* (gracias a [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php)) y lo vamos a asignar a la variable **$clave_array2**:

```
$clave_array2 = array_search($valor['documento'], array_column($array2, 'documento'));
```

- Ahora, sabiendo esa *$clave_array2* de *$array2*, donde sus valores de **documento** coinciden, simplemente agregamos el par `clave=>valor` en la posición actual, representada por *$clave*, dentro del ciclo, de *$array1*, mediante **$array1[$clave]**, y lo escribimos de este modo:

```
$array1[$clave]['url_foto'] = $array2[$clave_array2]['url_foto'];
```

- Una vez finalizados los ciclos mostramos el **$array1** con las modificaciones mediante un [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r):

```
print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que haría en lugar de utilizar arreglos sería craer un arreglo de objetos
donde creo una clase Persona y simplemente voy agregando uno a uno, en lugar de usar arreglos.
Primero creas la clase, despues el metodo constructor, luego los metodos setters y getters

```
class Persona(){
$persona= "
    public function __construct($persona = ""){
        $this->persona = $persona;
        
    }
        
public function setNombre($nombre){
       $this->nombre = $nombre;
       }
public function getNombre(){
 return $this->nombre;
        }    
        
}
```

Luego en el documento que quieras, importas el documento o lo mandas llamar con include('NombreDocument.PHP')
finalmente así cras un arreglo de objetos

```
$arr = array(
    new Persona(
        "Michelangelo",
        
    ),
    new Persona(
       "Acris",
        )
);
```

Finalmente para acceder a los datos, creas un objeto de la clase:

```
$obj = new Persona;
$obj->getNombre();
Espero ayudarte, arriverderla amico!
```

Comment: @Miguel_Olvera Gracias por el consejo, pero hacerlo así implicaría cambiar todo un código detrás y realmente no hay tiempo

Comment: Ah no te preocupes, suerte en lo que estas haciendo.